# From email address changes after email is sent (GMail postfix relay)

Tags: java, spring, gmail, jakarta-mail, postfix-mta

I've reached the limits of my SMTP/postfix knowledge.

I'm sending mail using javamail 1.4. The javamail library is connecting to a local postfix process. The postfix process is configured to relay mail through gmail.

```
relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587
```

Using the javamail lib, I'm setting the from address. But, when the mail ends up in my inbox, it is from the user that I'm using to log into the gmail server.

For example, in my code, I'm setting from to *noreply@example.com*. postfix is configured to relay mail through gmail, and it logs into the smtp server using *user1* and a password. The mail ends up in my inbox as if it's from *user1@example.com* (and there is not mention of *noreply@example.com* when I view the "original" from my gmail inbox).

It may be worth mentioning that I'm using Spring 3.0's library (MimeMessageHelper) on top of javamail.

Comment: I would try sending the same e-mail manually, that is without Java/Spring code at all. In your command line try with "telnet smtp.local.network 110", etc. If you get the same problem, it means the problem is with the SMTP infrastructure. Otherwise you would want to look into how you send e-mails in Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Google is rewriting the headers on your message to match the SMTP session's authenticated user.  [You can register other email addresses with your GMail account](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/configure_google_gmail_to_have_a_different_sender.html) ("custom From address"), in which case those other addresses will be accepted in the `From` header (though GMail will add the authenticated user in the `Sender` header).  [If you choose to use Google's SMTP server, there appears to be no way around this.](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370)

Comment: This is to prevent people from sending mail from addresses they don't have permission to send from...

Comment: This makes sense to me, thanks for the answer, dkarp. I'm in the process of testing out the solution right now.

Comment: And, just for reference, the solution worked.