# HP Scanner: send to mail with Google mail

Tags: raspberry-pi, sendmail, image-scanner

I have a Raspberry PI (rpi) and a HP Scanner at home that supports **scan2mail** (PDF, JPG). I want to send scans to my personal Google mail account. Unfortunately, HP does not support authentication on this printer.

I plan to use my rpi to forward (relay) e-mails. Do you think this will work? Is SMTP relay the technique I should use?

Comment: What means `HP does not support authentication` ?

Comment: Google mail requires you to authenticate before sending an e-mail. The firmware of my OLD printer does not support this feature. It only allows me to enter the SMTP-Host (IP or Hostname).

Comment: Ah, understand. It offers to configure the SMTP server but not credentials. Using an SMTP relay sounds ok then. (imo) Which alternatives do you have in mind?

Comment: @hek2mgl In the past I could directly send e-mails to Google and they were delivery even though directly move to SPAM. My biggest concern are that I need to store my password.

Comment: What about key based authentication? I personally never tried that with gmail so far but I found this: https://support.google.com/a/answer/174126?hl=en&ref_topic=2752442

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question. I installed postfix (`sudo apt-get install postfix`) and then followed a tutorial I found.

I want to highlight that the following option is required in order to make it work with **Gmail**:

```
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

With the `mail` command I can send a mail on the RPI itself. But remotely it does not work. I am still working on that :(

### Changing e-mail header

Unfortunately, this is not possible if you use Gmail ([see this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663040/from-email-address-changes-after-email-is-sent-gmail-postfix-relay)).